# Regex - Letters, numbers and symbols

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm new to regex and trying to create the expression for a string that is to consist of only:

- letters
- numbers
- Underscore symbol
- Period symbol (full stop)

So far I have this:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9,\.\_]/;
```

As I said I'm fairly new so expect this to be totally wrong!

Thanks.

Comment: You may (also) want to try [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this type of question.

Comment: `[\w\.]`? [Regular Expressions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
/^[a-z0-9._]+$/i
```

EDIT: David Thomas suggests a nice alternative: `/^[\w.]+$/i` -- possible locale issues.

You have a comma that I don't think you intend to have, but if you do just put it back.  the `i` modifier makes the expression case-insensitive.

Inside of character classes, periods don't need to be escaped (not relevant if you do: http://jsfiddle.net/pvgTT/1/)

You need the `^` and `$` (beginning and end of string) to match against the entire string.  Otherwise, it could match a string that has at least one such character but could also have others.

`+` (1 or more) is used.  Could also be `*` (0 or more).  Either is required since the length of the string is unknown.

Answer (score 3):

What you need more:

- A `^` at the beginning to match the beginning of the string
- A `$` at the end to match the end of the string
- A multiplier on the set so that it can match more than one character

The `+` multiplier makes the set match one or more characters. The comma should not be in the set, as you don't want to match commas. The `.` and `_` don't need escaping inside a set:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$
```

The `\w` code matches letters, digits and underscore, so you can use:

```
^[\w.]+$
```